# Get line as two point on cvCanny() in OpenCV

Tags: arrays, opencv, graphics, javacv

Sorry for stupid question. I want get line as two point, but cvCanny() put line in CvArr (image matrix). I can parse matrix for get line, but it slowly... I use JavaCV. Code example

```
IplImage image;
IplImage gray;
IplImage dst;
gray = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
dst = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
cvCanny(gray, dst, 100, 200, 3);
```

[Image result (dst object)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TycC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to find a line inside a picture, use [HoughLines](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html)

Of course, it is best to use it on the result of the edge detection (canny)